# Build Tables with relationships

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to build table on my website. Right now it's working fine:

```
<table id="objects" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Object Name</th>
            <th>Object Relation Names</th>
            <th>Object Relation Types</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @forelse($objects as $object)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $object->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $object->name }}</td>
                <td>
                    @foreach($object->relations as $relation)
                        {{ $relation->name }}
                    @endforeach
                </td>
                <td>
                    @foreach($object->relations as $relation)
                        {{ $relation->type }}
                    @endforeach
                </td>
            </tr>
        @empty
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="text-center">No results.</td>
            </tr>
        @endforelse
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Result:

```
--------------------------------------
|#|Name  |Relation Name|Relation Type|
--------------------------------------
| |      |Relation 1   |      1      |
|1|Name 1|Relation 2   |      2      |
| |      |Relation 3   |      1      |
--------------------------------------
| |      |Relation 1   |      1      |
|2|Name 2|Relation 2   |      1      |
```

But I'm thinking if it's possible to make only one foreach loop and inside it make . Something like that:

```
<table id="objects" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Object Name</th>
            <th>Object Relation Names</th>
            <th>Object Relation Types</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @forelse($objects as $object)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $object->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $object->name }}</td>
                @foreach($object->relations as $relation)
                    <td>{{ $relation->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $relation->type }}</td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @empty
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="text-center">No results.</td>
            </tr>
        @endforelse
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this case I'm getting something like this:

```
--------------------------------------
|#|Name  |Relation Name|Relation Type|
--------------------------------------
|1|Name 1|Relation 1   |      1      |Relation 2   |      2      |Relation 3   |      1      |
--------------------------------------
|2|Name 2|Relation 1   |      1      |Relation 2   |      1      |
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make something like this

```
        1   @forelse($objects as $object)
        2    <tr>
        3   <td>{{ $object->id }}</td>
        4   <td>{{ $object->name }}</td>
        5   @foreach($object->relations as $relation)
        6       <td>{{ $relation->name }}</td>
        7       <td>{{ $relation->type }}</td> 
        8   @endforeach
        9 </tr>
```

after line no. 7 add a break line tag to avoid this problem.

or try this. I have not tried it because I am not a home.

```
        1   @forelse($objects as $object)
        2    @foreach($object->relations as $relation)
        3    <tr>
        4   <td>{{ $object->id }}</td>
        5   <td>{{ $object->name }}</td>
        6       <td>{{ $relation->name }}</td>
        7       <td>{{ $relation->type }}</td> 
        8   @endforeach
        9 </tr>
```

Comment: In this case i'll get `<td>{{ $object->id }}</td><td>{{ $object->name }}</td>` multiple times, but I need them only once. look at my first result.